# CodeIgniter Path Issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-url

I am use Codeigniter to creat my site. it is a huge site with a lot of contents.

i use the default welcome controller for all pages.

the path is like this now 
http://mydomain.com/index.php/welcome

and my folder structure is like this

```
/root
  /codeigniter Application folder
      /controller
      /view
  /static/
      /images/
      /css/
      /pdf/
  .htaccess
```

because i am doing the content first, so all the images are set to absolute patch (http://mydomain.com/static/images/foldername/pc.jpg)

now when i use the rewrite to remove "inde.php" and "welcome"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|system|pdf|sitemap\.xml|profile.htm|^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+).asp|(.*)\.pdf|phpadmin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/welcome/$1 [L]
```

all css and image file are not accessible anymore.  I have nearly a thousand pages with images. I don't have the time to change the page one by one. the deadline is coming, please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the css-folder to your excluded rewriteconditions?

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|system|pdf|sitemap\.xml|profile.htm|^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+).asp|(.*)\.pdf|phpadmin)
```

Does not seem to exclude the folder css from rewriting (see images is excluded).

Try something like

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|system|pdf|sitemap\.xml|profile.htm|^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+).asp|(.*)\.pdf|phpadmin)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with your .htaccess file. We have a similar setup, and that url living outside of the `application` directory is available just as you have it with a direct url relative to its path. Check out the wiki at http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite for the correct way to set up your .htaccess file.

Edit to clarify: The url `http://mydomain.com/static/images/foldername/pc.jpg` should work. something about your .htaccess file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteCond $1 !^(**static**|index.php|images|robots.txt|system|pdf|sitemap.xml|profile.htm|^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+).asp|(.*).pdf|phpadmin)